# How to make a TableView out of different NSObjects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsobject

maybe somebody can help me. I Have different class objects. They'll get created in the TableView.m file with arrays as properties of these objects. How can I populate the TableView out of these Objects so that every cell contains on object? When I am adding the objects to an array I am getting an error, when I am running the simulator.

Error:
App1[6354:7304461] -[Object1 isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000455c00

I think that the TableView doensn't know how to create the cell. But I don't have enough experience to know what is really going on.

Thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


//creating first Object of NSObject Class Object1
    Object1 *object1Class = [[WLAN alloc]init];

    object1Class.object1PicsCreated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    object1Class.object1TextsCreated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [object1Class.object1PicsCreated addObject:object1Class.picsObject1];
    [object1Class.object1TextsCreated addObject:object1Class.textsObject1];


    //creating second Object of NSObject Class Object2
    Object1 *object1Class = [[WLAN alloc]init];

    object2Class.object2PicsCreated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    object2Class.object2TextsCreated = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [object1Class.object2PicsCreated addObject:object2Class.picsObject2];
    [object1Class.object2TextsCreated addObject:object2Class.textsObject2];

if (!_objects){
            _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        }

[_objects addObject:object1Class]
[_objects addObject:object2Class]


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return _objects.count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];



    cell.textLabel.text  = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: cell.textLabel.text  = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] wrong initialization, return type of object is not NSString.

Comment: what type is it, how should i initialize it instead?

Comment: cell.textLabel.text is NSString Type so your object having some label text that you can assign with  cell.textLabel.text

Answer (score 0):

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode crashes because you pass an instance of `Object1` to the setter which expects `NSString`. `UITableView` thinks that object is `NSString` so calls `NSString`'s methods against it (for you it was `-isEqualToString:`), which is a reason it crashes.

Whatever you want to show needs to be converted to `NSString` before you pass it there.

> How can I populate the TableView out of these Objects so that every cell contains on object?

This is a very strange question. `UITableView`'s rows are `UITableViewCell`-s. You may not populate a table with anything else.

Maybe, you should describe your tasks in more details.